# Pandas: Row wise count for multiple columns after filter based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` as

```
Decile    2_Con    3_Con    6_Con   Pred
   1        0        0        0       0
   1        0        0        1       1
   1        0        0        1       1
   2        0        0        0       0
   2        0        1        0       1
   2        0        1        1       1
```

Objective:

I want to compute the count of 6_Con, 3_Con and 2_Con when I filter the above `df` by Pred and set 6_Con ,3_con and 2_Con to 1 for each Decile.

So the resultant Dataframe should look like:

```
   Decile      2_Con     3_Con      6_Con    Pred
     1           0         0          2        2      <--We are only counting 1 in the columns for each Decile
     2           0         2          1        2
```

How to achieve this? I am not able to generate a plausible code here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `df.groupby('Decile',as_index=False).sum()`

Comment: if you want take count where not is 0: `df.ne(0).gropuby('decile',as_index = False).sum()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try:

```
df = df.groupby('Decile').sum()
```

This makes sense because of the 0-1 values, hence, the sum will be the count of non 0 values (rows) for each different decile.

Comment: I have used `groupby().agg()` for suitable Transformation